# Serialize an Object to XML: IList<CustomObject> Property Causes Exception

Tags: c#, serialization

I am using the following function to attempt to serialize an object to XML..

```
 public static string SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                string xmlString = null;
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj);
                memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
                xmlString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray()); return xmlString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

When attempting to serialize an object that has an IList property in it, I get the following exception..

```
Cannot serialize member 'ObjectModel.Order.LineItems' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList
```

Can someone help me change my function to accommodate for this scenario?

Is there anything I can do this existing code to look into the input object. If its of type Ilist change it to a List? Can somoeone help me with code for that if its at all possible??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no great solution for this, only the workaround of using a concrete type like `List<T>` in this case - you could either change the existing property to be `List<T>` or add an additional property used just for serialization of type `List<T>` (and XML-ignore your existing property).

Comment: Can I check for an IList in the input object and if it exist change it ToList on the fly?

Comment: No that's not really possible, you have to change your class definition

Answer (score 0):

XmlSerializer does not handle properties of type `IList<T>`.  There are some workarounds, the most straightforward of which is to change the type of the property:

https://www.google.com/search?q=xmlserializer+ilist

Answer (score -1):

How important is Xml output?  binary format is more accomodating. you could convert the output to base64 string if needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.71).aspx