# How to serialize an object containing an ILIST member into XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to convert an object say User having multiple fields into an XML. The problem is that I get an exception when it tries to serialize an ILIST member.
Following is the code I am using:

```
var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(); 
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(User.GetType()); <!-- Getting exception here -->
serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, User); 
return stringwriter.ToString();
```

My User looks something like this:

```
class User
{       public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual int? ContactId { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }
        public virtual AccessLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way by which I can check if a member of the class whose object I am serializing is serializable or not and then tweak the logic for that particular member. I have less control over the user class. :( So any way where I could extend my code to handle IList members will be preferred.

Comment: try mark `User` class as `serializable`, for that add [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: `User` in your code it and class and object or only class?

Comment: Cannot serialize member 'User.Sectors' of type 'System.Collections.IList

Comment: While serializing User is an instance not class.

Comment: try see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632769/cannot-serialize-member-because-it-is-an-interface), so you simply should not use interface

Comment: here is the same topic  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012736/how-to-serialize-an-interface-such-as-ilistt

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize an Object to XML: IList<CustomObject> Property Causes Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879618/serialize-an-object-to-xml-ilistcustomobject-property-causes-exception)

Answer (score 6):

The old style XML serialization can't handle interfaces - it wants concrete types.

However, you can do it with the newer [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's an example based on your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace Demo
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual DateTime? LastUpdated
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual int? ContactId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual IList<string> Sectors
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            User user = new User();

            user.Sectors = new[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
            user.Name = "Test Name";

            // Serialize

            var result = new StringBuilder();
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(user.GetType());

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(result))
            using (var xmlWriter    = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true } ))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, user);
            }

            string serialisedToString = result.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(serialisedToString);

            // Deserialize

            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(serialisedToString))
            using (var xmlReader    = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                user = (User) serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way by which I can check if a member of the class whose object I am serializing is serializable or not and then tweak the logic for that particular member. I have less control over the user class. :( So any way where I could extend my code to handle IList members will be preferred.